# Ensure an msbuild task is run at the end of the build

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I am looking at improving one of our build systems, but it's a bit of an unorganised mess. I want to add a task which is run at the end of a Release build only and after all other tasks we have such as FxCop/StyleCop/signing processes.

Is there an easy way of specifying a task that you want at the absolute end of a build? I've currently got the task running after the build (using AfterBuild Target) but this doesn't make sense for what the task is doing.

Cheers,
Jamie

Comment: `AferBuild` is meant specifically for this, why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Because we have a lot of AfterBuild targets already. Would I need to add a new task with a dependency on the current last target?

Or I suppose another question is, is there a tool to view what targets are run where (GUI or otherwise?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Targets tag takes "DependsOnTargets" attribute and "Condition" attribute. You can effectively use these attributes in AfterBuild.